# File upload control not working on ipad

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipad

I have an web application in which i want to upload images.
its working fine on windows,but file upload control is not accessible on iPad.

Can you please tell me whats a problem and how i can solve this problem..

```
 <input id="file3" type="file" runat="server" name="file3" class="textfield" style="WIDTH: 221px; HEIGHT: 20px;" size="17"/>
```

Comment: I sense a quick closure and massive down-votes for this question in the near future. You should edit this question a.s.a.p. to provide more detail as to what you are trying to do, what you've already done (and show code), etc. etc.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: i have html file upload control on my web page which is not accessible on iPad. there is no error but when i browse web page control is not disabled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To access IOS file system follow these steps :

1.)First create a IOS application.

2.)Then access that perticular application and upload file.

to follow this procedure refer this [LINK](http://picupapp.com/)

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

IOS does not support accessing the file system. As such, any `<input type="file" />` elements on your page will be ignored by Mobile Safari.

Comment: my web application is in dot.net  and i tried using asp.net file upload control but still there is same problem. is there any alternative for this

Comment: It has nothing to do with .net, the Apple OS doesn't allow the browser to access the file system